# Migrations for PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, svn, postgresql, redgate

Red-Gate has very interesting in beta software ([Sql Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Source_Control/index.htm)) that is installing inside SSMS and can save schema iterations through commit button. I need the same feature for postgresql, the only way i found similar to this - is log_statement = ddl, but log need be transformed and saved properly to file and than commited. What is your opinion about postgresql iteration tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Post Facto](http://www.post-facto.org/) is similar to what you want.

Comment: Post Facto is now the home page of an education sector services company. Can you update the link?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly like Red Gate's tool, but check out http://www.liquibase.org/. Might pique your interest considering your topic.

Answer (score 0):

[Another PostgreSQL Diff Tool (apgdiff)](http://apgdiff.startnet.biz/) sounds like it works a lot like Red Gate's SQL Source Control and SQL Compare:

> Another PostgreSQL Diff Tool (also known as apgdiff) is free
>   PostgreSQL diff tool that is useful for comparison/diffing of database
>   schemas. The tool compares two database dump files and creates output
>   with DDL statements that can be used to update old database schema to
>   new one or to see in what exactly both databases differ.